# Laravel 5.2 How to delete parent record from belongsTo relationship?

Tags: laravel

My Pricing model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'zone_id',
    'is_short_time',
    'is_service_feeder',
    'route_id',
    'value',    
];

public function route()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Route::class);    
}
```

My Route Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'zone_id',
    'from_city_id',
    'to_city_id',
    'is_in_the_city',    
];

public function pricing(){
    return $this->hasOne(Pricing::class);    
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public function feeder_destroy($zoneid, $pricingfeederid)
{
    $pricing_feeder = Pricing::find($pricingfeederid)->where('zone_id', $zoneid)->where('is_service_feeder', 1);
    $pricing_feeder->route()->delete();
    $pricing_feeder->delete();
}
```

The error says

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::route()
```

I want to delete pricing record and route record too.

What wrong with my code? How should it's look like?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $pricing_feeder->route->delete(); try this

Comment: @JagadeshaNH I get this Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$route

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should

```
$pricing_feeder = Pricing::find($pricingfeederid)->where('zone_id', $zoneid)->where('is_service_feeder', 1)->first();
```

Dont forget `first()` at the end.

Then use like so `$pricing_feeder->route->delete();`

Comment: This query has a problem as it will execute two queries, `find()` and `first()` will fetch data two times for the same result. Instead, you can replace `find()` with `where('id', $pricingfeederid)`. I have added the answer, you can check it for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `$pricing_feeder->route->delete();` Removing `()` from `route()`

Your error is on the `relation`, not the `Parent`.

Comment: I get this Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$route

Answer (score 0):

not the fanciest but you can delete the **route** that comes with **pricing** by adding this method to your **route** model

```
public function delete()
{
    // delete all related pricing 
    $this->pricing()->delete();

    // delete the route as well
    return parent::delete();
}
```

then just call `$pricing_feeder->route->delete();`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have this model relationships

In **Post** model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In **User** model

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

and the following code deleted all the posts and the user

```
$user = \App\User::findOrFail(1);
$user->post[1]->delete();
$user->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, becouse you need to add a `first()` method call:

```
    $pricing_feeder = Pricing::find($pricingfeederid)->where('zone_id', $zoneid)->where('is_service_feeder', 1)->first();
```

Than I'd check the returned object if is null. If is not, than you can delete the related relationship and the model as well.

Also, when calling the `delete()` methods use the relationships as follows:

```
    $pricing_feeder->route->delete();
```